# How to change from pop os to ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

My friend has installed pop OS from windows 7 on my old pc. Now i want to switch to ubuntu. I found no detailed YouTube videos of how to change from pop os to ubuntu. Please someone guide me through this process.

Comment: Just reinstall.

Comment: It can only be done via re-install; as Pop OS use *tricks* to ensure Ubuntu packages don't replace the Pop OS ones (ie. inflate their package versions) which prevent what you wish to do.  You can re-install and not lose your files, and have your *manually installed* packages auto-reinstalled, but having used Pop OS you'd have a little bit of preparation to do before you could implement this (*esp. for package auto-reinstall; not if you only want your data to survive*) but you didn't provide release details so this is likewise more generic advice (ie. adjust for releases; it's easier for some).

Answer (score 2):

Insert the installation DVD or USB, boot from it and perform a standard installation, using the entire drive.

Needles to say: make sure your backup of your personal data is up to date, because an install erases the contents of the disk. After installation, copy your data into the new install.